# Nginx failed to bind and redirection

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm trying to configure my reverse proxy through nginx using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial, but when I go to restart the nginx server, it throws the following error message:

```
nginx[12681]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I checked out the port using netstat, and I have the following result

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

What does this mean? When I go to my domain name, it redirects to the Centos page instead of an nginx page I should be getting. How can I configure the file to get it to redirect to nginx?

Edit:

Added httpd status

```
httpd.service                                 disabled
mysql.service                                 enabled
my_api.service                                enabled
nginx.service                                 disabled
```

I get the above errors when I try to start nginx using systemctl

Comment: Use `netstat -pna |grep :80` to see what process already listen on port 80.

Comment: I only get what I've written above.

Comment: Check httpd (apache) service status.

Comment: `httpd.service                                 disabled`

Comment: What is `lsof -i :80` output?

Comment: Nothing, no result

Comment: Show the `proxy_pass` line from your nginx config. It looks like you're pointing nginx at itself, rather than at the reverse proxy.

Comment: share `netstat -tunlp | grep :80` command. Make sure that you are using only single Listen entry for 80 port.

Answer (score 0):

Running `netstat -luntp` as root showed that nginx had spawned a master process and a worker. Killing those processes solved the issue